# writing column entry just one below another in python

Tags: python

I have imported a file containing 8 columns, each column separated by `'\t'`, so during import all `'\t'` are replaced by `'space'` and `'\n'` are split to make indexing easier for me. Then a list is generated form input file for further analysis. But after analysis I got

```
lst =  ['PAIR', '1MFK', 'URANIUM', '82', 'HELIUM', '112', 3.6997']
```

kind of list, so I put

```
final = '    '.join(lst)
```

to get the values like `PAIR 1MFK 1 URANIUM 82 HELIUM 112 3.6997`
But when I print all values it comes as following

```
PAIR 1MFK 1 URANIUM 82 HELIUM 112 3.6997  
PAIR 2JGH 2 PLUTONIUM 98 POTASSIUM 88 5.3003  
PAIR 345G 3 SODIUM 23 CARBON 14 1.664  
PAIR 4IG5 4 LITHIUM 82 ARGON 99 2.5506
```

here the column entries don't lie just one below another however indentation is same for all.

I have tried with `'\t'` but that produce same randomized result.
please help.

Comment: where does the first `**` come from? how are you printing each line, can you show some code?

Comment: missing final ' in lst for 3.6997 .. and commas to separate items in the list?

Comment: I wrote a [little tabulator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577458-simple-tabulator/?in=user-4173873) a long time ago that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do something simple like this..

```
>>> s = '''PAIR 1MFK 1 URANIUM 82 HELIUM 112 3.6997  
... PAIR 2JGH 2 PLUTONIUM 98 POTASSIUM 88 5.3003  
... PAIR 345G 3 SODIUM 23 CARBON 14 1.664  
... PAIR 4IG5 4 LITHIUM 82 ARGON 99 2.5506'''
>>> ll = [x.split() for x in s.split('\n')]
>>> for row in ll:
...   print ''.join(x.ljust(10) for x in row)
... 
PAIR      1MFK      1         URANIUM   82        HELIUM    112       3.6997    
PAIR      2JGH      2         PLUTONIUM 98        POTASSIUM 88        5.3003    
PAIR      345G      3         SODIUM    23        CARBON    14        1.664     
PAIR      4IG5      4         LITHIUM   82        ARGON     99        2.5506
```

Here I am using a fixed column width of 10 characters.  If you like, you can make it slightly more sophisticated by calculating appropriate column widths beforehand.

```
>>> column_widths = [max(len(x) for x in l) for l in zip(*ll)]
>>> for row in ll:
...   print '  '.join(x.ljust(w) for x,w in zip(row, column_widths))
... 
PAIR  1MFK  1  URANIUM    82  HELIUM     112  3.6997
PAIR  2JGH  2  PLUTONIUM  98  POTASSIUM  88   5.3003
PAIR  345G  3  SODIUM     23  CARBON     14   1.664 
PAIR  4IG5  4  LITHIUM    82  ARGON      99   2.5506
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have **too** many lists, you could do something like this:

```
lst1 =  ['PAIR','1MFK','1','URANIUM','82','HELIUM','112','3.6997']
lst2 = 'PAIR 2JGH 2 PLUTONIUM 98 POTASSIUM 88 5.3003'.split(' ')
lst3 = 'PAIR 345G 3 SODIUM 23 CARBON 14 1.664'.split(' ')
lst4 = 'PAIR 4IG5 4 LITHIUM 82 ARGON 99 2.5506'.split(' ')
lsts = [lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4]
sizes = [max(len(item) for item in l) + 2 for l in zip(*lsts)]
for lst in lsts:
    print "".join(word.ljust(sizes[i]) for i, word in enumerate(lst))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PAIR  1MFK  1  URANIUM    82  HELIUM     112  3.6997  
PAIR  2JGH  2  PLUTONIUM  98  POTASSIUM  88   5.3003  
PAIR  345G  3  SODIUM     23  CARBON     14   1.664   
PAIR  4IG5  4  LITHIUM    82  ARGON      99   2.5506
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to guess how much you need to pad by.

Comment: i have actually 300+ lines...so i think it would be tiresome in this way.

Comment: good.  the list comprehensions are unnecessary (and inefficient) inside join and max though.

Comment: @wim: Right you are... fixed.

Comment: @abhisek:  Why tiresome?  You could add the lists to the lsts list as you read them from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming each line of input becomes a list (`lst`) for processing. Inside your processing loop you could use formatting directives with your print to line up the output.

Given your current input line/`lst`:

```
lst =  ['PAIR', '1MFK', 'URANIUM', '82', 'HELIUM', '112', '3.6997']
final = ' '.join(lst)
```

then:

```
print('%8s %8s %10s %4s %10s %5s %10s' % (tuple(final.split())))
```

You could adjust the field widths to suit your needs.

If you needed numbers to line up  you could convert the strings into numbers via `int()` or `float()` and then use the appropriate formatting directives to line up the decimal points, for instance using `%7.4f` for your floats, and `%4d` for your ints (again, pick values that meet your needs)