# Why does assignment of split to print formatting not work?

Tags: python, string, split, string-formatting

I am puzzled why I can assign/unpack the return of `split()` to the
appropriate number of variables, but the same fails for use in a
print string using formatting directives.

E.g., given:

```
In [202]: s
Out[202]: 'here are 4 values'

In [203]: s.split()
Out[203]: ['here', 'are', '4', 'values']
```

This works as expected:

```
In [204]: a, b, c, d = s.split()

In [205]: print '%s %s %s %s' % (a, b, c, d)
here are 4 values
```

But this fails ..

```
 In [206]: print '%s %s %s %s' % (s.split())
```

I am not sure why? Shouldn't the return of `split()` be
unpacked and be distributed over the expected arguments for the
formatting strings?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\bla\Desktop\<ipython-input-206-600f130ff0b2> in <module>()
----> 1 print '%s %s %s %s' % (s.split())

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

"Note enough arguments" .. I do have the right number of items in the list. Does the list for some reason not unpack in this case, but does with assignments to variables?

I came across this in attempting to answer this question
[writing column entry just one below another in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10394091/1209279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must convert `s.split()` into a tuple like so

```
>>> s = 'here are 4 values'
>>> '%s %s %s %s' % tuple(s.split())
'here are 4 values'
```

for formatting or use [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead, unpacking the arguments.

```
'{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(*s.split())
```

Comment: that works - thanks. Is the tuple required because what I supply to my print statement at the end following the % is a tuple (rather than a list of arguments as I have thought about them until now)?

Comment: Yes I believe it requires a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental problem is that `%`-formatting and unpacking aren't related at all. The `%` *requires* that the values be in a tuple; other kinds of sequences [won't work](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). (It will accept a single non-tuple value though.)

This has the unfortunate consequence that all tuples are interpreted as tuples of values, whether or not that's desirable. So to treat a tuple *as* a value, you have to encase it in another tuple:

```
>>> '%s' % ('a', 'b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>> '%s' % (('a', 'b'),)
"('a', 'b')"
```

Using `format` is preferable anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks ... I was wondering about that. Until now I thought of the items in parenthesis supplied after the final `%` as a parameter list rather than a tuple, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that % doesn't allow argument unpacking.  Here's a method that works:

```
>>> s = 'Here are some values'
>>> '{} {} {} {}'.format(*s.split())
'Here are some values'
```

@senderle pointed out that this syntax only works for python 2.7 and up, here is code that will work with previous versions:

```
>>> s = 'Here are some values'
>>> '{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(*s.split())
'Here are some values'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'here are 4 values'
>>> print '%s %s %s %s' % tuple(s.split())
here are 4 values
>>> print '%s' % s.split()
['here', 'are', '4', 'values']
```

Python is trying to convert list to string so it requires only 1 parameter